# Error invoking Method 'addNewDriveToSadranTable': Internal server error [500]

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a problem with Meteor.Call and methods.

I put `console.log('test')` in the method code. The console shows it, and I can see new doc in the collection for a millisecond (and then it is gone).

what can be the bug?

**client/sidurEditor.js**

```
Template.sidurEditor.helpers({
    showForSadran: function() {
        return ForSadranDrives.find({},{sort: {askedDate: 1, since: 1}});
    }
```

**lib/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods ({
addNewDriveToSadranTable: function (askedDate, since, until, askedDrive, askedUser) {
    console.log('click');
    ForSadranDrives.insert({
        askedDate: askedDate,
        since: since,
        until: until,
        askedDrive: askedDrive,
        driveCar: "chooseCar",
        driveCarName: "car undefined",
        driveDriver: "driver undefined",
        askedUser: askedUser,
        askedNickName: Session.get('nickName'),
        onEditDriveRow: false
    });
    console.log('click2');
} });
```

**collection/collections.js**

```
ForSadranDrives = new Mongo.Collection('forsadrandrives');
```

Comment: Session is not available on the server, so this is probably your error. Send all of the required data to the server as arguments.

Comment: @masterAM how can i send all the required data to the server as arguments?

Comment: From your client, send `askedNickName` as an argument the same way you send `askedDate`, etc.

Comment: @MasterAM 
thanks!!! that solved the problem
i wrote it as the answer (you wrote me as comment)
thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was that I wrote a Session inside the method... i putted it in the Meteor.call(...) as argument and it runs great!!

thanks to @masterAM for the comment and the answer

so it look now like that:

**client/navbar.js**

```
            Meteor.call('addNewDriveToSadranTable',askedDate, since, until, askedDrive, askedUser, Session.get('nickName'));
```

**lib/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods ({
addNewDriveToSadranTable: function (askedDate, since, until, askedDrive, askedUser, askedNickName) {
    console.log('click1');
    ForSadranDrives.insert({
        askedDate: askedDate,
        since: since,
        until: until,
        askedDrive: askedDrive,
        driveCar: "chooseCar",
        driveCarName: "אין רכב מוגדר",
        driveDriver: "אין נהג מוגדר",
        askedUser: askedUser,
        askedNickName: askedNickName,
        onEditDriveRow: false
    });
    console.log('click2');
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is Meteor's latency compensation - the record is inserted into the local db (minimongo), but disappears when the database refresh from the server occurs. It is most likely because your subscription to the data is either missing or your filter is exluding the data.

You can check by looking for the record in the mongo shell, with the command

```
meteor mongo
```

Make sure your cd is in the project directory

Comment: i am not sure what should i do, i put the methods outside the Meteor.isServer and Meteor.isClient
what should i add? or where should be that filter you wrote about?